# About product limit to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer

```
 I want to know is there a way or plugin to set the following rules:
```

one product can only allow purchase 2 per customer.
For example: Customer A can buy product A for qty <2, after payment Customer A cannot buy the product A.

So it is not only restrict for product A only set for qty maximum to 2, it is also can check for Customer all order can only buy for product A for 2.

Comment: see the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778026/magento-limit-product-max-quantity-per-customer-not-per-order